# Enable CDN for Slideshows Using PNP Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, cdn

This is probably a noobie question as I'm still new to managing SharePoint Online using PowerShell.

I was looking at a post from here to enable CDN on the picture library for slideshows. The issue i'm facing is that it is still using the `Get-SPO` verbiage.

```
Get-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private

Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private -Enable $true 
Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Private 
Add-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Private -OriginUrl */libname
```

I can't find any `Get`/`Set-Pnp` cdn cmdlets.  Any help, link, or references is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is not an API to achieve this feature in pnp-powershell currently. Check the article below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/pnp-powershell-overview

We need use the PowerShell below to achieve it in currently.

```
$spo = Read-Host 'Enter your SPO Service URL. (example https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com)'
$origin = Read-Host 'Enter the url to the CDN.  (example https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/Media/CDNLibrary)'
connect-sposervice $spo
$tenant = Get-SPOTenant
Set-SPOTenant -PublicCdnEnabled $true
$tenant = Get-SPOTenant
New-SPOPublicCdnOrigin -url $origin
```